# Using querystrings with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a URL www.mydomain.com/jobs?applications=2|4|6

I am trying to get the values to work with my Input::get but failing.  I have tried using array but this doesn't work.  Can anyone advise?  I'm unfamiliar with using Laravel with this structure of querystring.

```
$applicationIDs = Input::get('applications');

$applications = Job::with('users');

if(!empty($applicationIDs)){
     $applications->whereIn('id', $applicationIDs);
}

$applications = $applications->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `applications` parameter is just a string. Use `explode` to turn it into an array of ids:

```
$applicationIDs = explode('|', Input::get('applications'));
```